# Datatype for phone numbers in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-design, sqldatatypes

I am new to postgresql so can anyone tell me that is there any specific datatype to store phone numbers in postgresql while creating table in pgadmin or is it just string?

Comment: Please see the following link : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164796/how-do-i-store-phone-numbers-in-postgresql

Comment: Better to use `character`

Comment: @ZakirHossain: no, [don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29) use `text` or `character varying`.

Comment: I saw the link but it does not mention the datatype like text or serial etc . So should I go for text datatype

Comment: you should use string

Comment: Voting to close as this has [already been covered](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164796/how-do-i-store-phone-numbers-in-postgresql)  on sister site, DBA.StackExchange.com.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I recommend to use `text` and add a check constraint that tests the phone number for validity.

This is a good use case for [domains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html). Particularly if you need such a column in several places, it is convenient to have a domain that includes the check constraint.

Comment: Where domain might look like:`CREATE DOMAIN iol.phone_number AS TEXT
    CHECK(
        VALUE ~ '^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$'
    );`

Comment: true. This regex doesn't allow for country codes. It is what I added for an app for a US-based organization after your pointing me to domains. I just thought a little example might help if that link ever moves.

Comment: Or for US, the domain might look as simple as `CREATE DOMAIN iol.phone_number AS VARCHAR(10) CHECK(VALUE ~ '^[0-9]{10}$');`

Comment: so what will work for all countries?

Comment: @uberrebu Probably nothing. If I were you, I would not check the number for correctness at all in that case.

Answer (score 5):

You can store contact number in **BIGINT** and **VARCHAR**.

But with a trade off between security and performance. If you bother about performance (using a big dataset) then you should choose bigint  but do read this first [Google says never store phone numbers as numeric data](https://www.mayerdan.com/programming/2017/06/26/db_phone_types)
If you do not bother about performance as data set is not soo large then go with varchar.

src - [ https://www.mayerdan.com/programming/2017/06/26/db_phone_types ]